# Continuous clocked concurrent SQL table inserts over a RESTful WCF service slowing down until the clients receive HTTP timeouts

Tags: c#, sql-server, rest, wcf, concurrency

I'm developing a WCF webservice (*HTTP, REST*) to enable event logging to external clients / devices to a database table. These logs shall be stored on a database (in this case *MS SQL Server*). The backend uses *ODBC* to connect to the database, because it should be compatible to multiple DBMS.

But I'm running into concurrency issues on the datatabase inserts. Currently I simulate 4 clients, that continuously log events (*one REST method call every second; started at the same time*). The service writes the transmitted information to the same table on the database. But after a while, the clients sometimes won't get a HTTP-responses due to timeouts, because some inserts will be queued too long.

The service calls the following Method on each REST-Call (I removed Stopwatch lines):

```
private static bool AddReportToDatabase(...)
{
    Database database = new OdbcDatabase(ConfigurationHandler.GetDatabaseConfigParameters());

    var dateTime = DateTime.Now;

    try
    {
        int rowsAffected = 0;

        database.Connect();
        // Note: In fact, here is only one row => theres no performance issue due to the foreach loop
        foreach (var row in csv.Rows)
        {
            // build insert statement and execute
            var insertStatement = DatabaseHelper.BuildInsertRowSqlStatement(row, ...);

            rowsAffected += database.SqlExecute(insertStatement);
        }

        // return stuff.
        return rowsAffected > 0 || csv.Rows.Count == 0;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        database.Disconnect();

        Console.WriteLine(stopwatchString);
    }
}
```

The SqlExecute Method of that Database wrapper:

```
public override int SqlExecute(string statement, bool autoCloseConnection = false)
{
    // Check parameters.
    if (statement is null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(statement)); }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(statement)) { throw new ArgumentException(); }

    OdbcCommand cmd = null;
    int rowCount = 0;

    try
    {
        if (_connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) { ReConnect(); }
        if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cmd = new OdbcCommand(statement, _connection);
            rowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd?.Dispose();
        if (autoCloseConnection) { _connection?.Close(); }
    }
    return rowCount;
}
```

I started writing the time durations, for some operations that are called in the AddReportToDatabase(...) method, to the console.
An excerpt from the Visual Studio (Debug mode) output shows the Problem:

```
Connection: 00:00:43.3932743, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000389, Insertion execution: 00:00:08.2686554, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0010952
Connection: 00:00:35.2980692, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000205, Insertion execution: 00:00:08.4519441, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000165
Connection: 00:00:22.5600041, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0022653, Insertion execution: 00:00:09.0177640, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000160
Connection: 00:00:40.7761234, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000155, Insertion execution: 00:00:08.5453105, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000098
Connection: 00:00:40.4190963, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000142, Insertion execution: 00:00:08.5454255, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000062
Connection: 00:00:35.6413547, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000319, Insertion execution: 00:00:08.5458726, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000061
Connection: 00:00:33.2825363, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000291, Insertion execution: 00:00:09.4197485, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000173
Connection: 00:00:14.5735937, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000301, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.7464504, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000189
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Core.dll
Connection: 00:00:00.0006277, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000175, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.6230868, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000289
Connection: 00:00:00.0009455, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000238, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.3431754, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000179
Connection: 00:00:10.7779260, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000271, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.9052707, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000163
Connection: 00:00:06.7611688, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000492, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.6356935, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000194
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Core.dll
Connection: 00:00:46.1030176, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000149, Insertion execution: 00:00:12.0938001, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000191
Connection: 00:00:09.6917265, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000296, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.5381473, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000184
Connection: 00:00:40.6265686, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000238, Insertion execution: 00:00:03.8422172, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000178
Connection: 00:00:00.0006520, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000171, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.5489864, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000117
Connection: 00:00:00.0007138, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000168, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.6436385, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000087
Connection: 00:00:00.0006049, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000175, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.8492274, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000383
Connection: 00:00:00.0005660, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000188, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.9499183, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000230
Connection: 00:00:00.0009943, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000438, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.3964118, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000197
Connection: 00:00:00.0005547, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000181, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.3838526, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000192
Connection: 00:00:00.0007199, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000209, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.9477482, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000206
Connection: 00:00:00.0006825, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000206, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.1694541, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000182
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Core.dll
Connection: 00:00:00.0007774, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000279, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.8400186, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000175
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Core.dll
Connection: 00:00:00.0006994, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000154, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.3693845, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000184
Connection: 00:00:00.0008125, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000274, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.8685170, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000177
Connection: 00:00:00.0009804, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000198, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.4191057, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000090
Connection: 00:00:00.0005996, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000160, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.5557408, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000193
Connection: 00:00:00.0008110, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000190, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.3741617, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000166
Connection: 00:00:00.0006637, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000165, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.3732236, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000203
Connection: 00:00:00.0006747, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000152, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.3712866, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000118
Connection: 00:00:00.0031405, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000231, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.5106569, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000191
Connection: 00:00:00.0033558, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000184, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.8863036, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000178
Connection: 00:00:00.2706784, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000267, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.4607328, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000095
Connection: 00:00:00.0008118, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000194, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.1763091, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000080
Connection: 00:00:00.0007023, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000331, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.0291836, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000165
Connection: 00:00:00.0006962, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000175, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.4053649, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000237
Connection: 00:00:00.0006658, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000174, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.8583524, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000337
Connection: 00:00:00.0005899, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000158, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.8663091, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000185
Connection: 00:00:00.0010868, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000313, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.6851859, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000168
The thread 0x80c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3138 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x55c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3788 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Connection: 00:00:00.0012492, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000348, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.6995635, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000164
Connection: 00:00:00.0006438, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000165, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.2950788, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000175
Connection: 00:00:00.0006178, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000159, Insertion execution: 00:00:03.1707274, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000169
Connection: 00:00:00.0007568, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000176, Insertion execution: 00:00:03.2457625, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000190
Connection: 00:00:00.0007487, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000187, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.3998818, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000144
Connection: 00:00:00.0021411, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000171, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.5465371, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000164
Connection: 00:00:00.0006600, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000220, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.8264877, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000166
Connection: 00:00:00.0006120, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000178, Insertion execution: 00:00:02.1364418, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000169
Connection: 00:00:00.0006415, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000167, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.3577112, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000182
Connection: 00:00:00.0018622, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000187, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.9203211, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000911
Connection: 00:00:00.0008004, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000154, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.9627891, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000131
Connection: 00:00:00.0007099, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000172, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.4785908, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000179
Connection: 00:00:00.0008012, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000176, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.5589073, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000189
Connection: 00:00:00.0007580, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000186, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.3407059, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000162
Connection: 00:00:00.0006188, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000196, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.3752180, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000037
Connection: 00:00:00.0007519, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000169, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.4691674, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000046
Connection: 00:00:00.0006486, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000151, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.7363978, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000312
Connection: 00:00:00.0007112, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000195, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.4897923, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000167
Connection: 00:00:00.0009538, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000280, Insertion execution: 00:00:00.6982814, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000331
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Core.dll
Connection: 00:00:00.0010226, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000198, Insertion execution: 00:00:02.2475417, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000154
Connection: 00:00:00.0007328, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000192, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.4527606, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000084
Connection: 00:00:00.0010429, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000224, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.9530475, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000264
Connection: 00:00:00.0006835, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000277, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.5596577, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000056
Connection: 00:00:00.0010008, INSERT statement build: 00:00:00.0000673, Insertion execution: 00:00:01.8743239, Disconnection: 00:00:00.0000062
```

As you can see, the first connections take very long to success (This problem does not exist when I simulate with only one client). In addition the insertions sometimes take more than one second. And now and then much longer (e.G. 12 seconds) to insert a row into the database. As a result, the wait time of some calls will reach the HTTP timeout and the operation will be canceled. I guess that depens (partially) on the DBMS and it's table writing management.
Another thing is, that there are multiple System.TimeoutExceptions thrown internally in the System.Core.dll and written to the output, which I cannot explain. So I can't tell if they're relevant or not.

The *WCF* Service is running with the default service behavior for session instancing and concurrency ([https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/sessions-instancing-and-concurrency](http://Microsoft:%20Sessions,%20Instancing,%20and%20Concurrency)),
which should be equal to the usage of the following code:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
```

So to my understanding, there is a new thread (instance context) created on each REST-Call. These should be managed by the WCF Service.

Is the problem a configuration Issue on the database (MVCC=true did not help), or on the web service? 
To the implementation: I've tried a singleton database instance, but that caused other database access issues. And a global mutex to handle the database command executions, slows the whole thing down.
I even removed the PK-Constraint from the table to exclude (or at least reduce the probability) subsequent issues due to indexing.

Another version of this Service acts as this should, but with the difference that it logs on local files instead of a database. Here I used a mutex to handle the file access and that works even with quite shorter/faster logging frequencies (eg. a event log each 250ms). Mutexing the Insertion did not help here.

By the way: The WCF Service is self hosted by a Windows service.

**UPDATE**:

I found the cause of the problem.
The REST/WCF Method that is called is the following:

```
public bool Report(...)
{
    NotifyGUI(someStringParameter);
    return ReportHandler.AddReport(...); // this calls implicitly AddReportToDatabase(...) in this scenario
}
```

The firstly called method causes the Exceptions:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Core.dll
```

and blocks the main functionality (connect, write to table and disconnect), so it causes the delays that grind my gears.

```
private void NotifyGUI(string s)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var client = new NamedPipeClientStream(typeof(HttpService).ToString()))
        {
            client.Connect(5000);
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(s);
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I would check the Event Viewer on PC to see if more info about the timeout is in the logs.

Comment: I don't find any helpful log in the event viewer.

Comment: Do you now if the exception is being caused by the connection or the disconnection?  It may pay use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to determine exactly where the error is occurring.  Check the TCP FIN and make sure it close it getting ACK.  You may be disposing the connection too soon so the ACK doesn't occur which is giving the exception.  A server should never close a connection only the client.  When both client and server try to close a connection at the same time exceptions can occur.

Comment: I have no idea what's causing the exception. It does not break the program, When I remove the catch blocks, the debugger did not break on the occurance of the exceptions (it is just logged to the output). Maybe the exception is not affecting the program or causing the issue. Removing the explicit Dispose() calls did not change anything (I did not remove them from the destructors). Or it a internal threading / synchronization problem.
If there were problems with the connection to the database, there should be other exceptions thrown. Or at least these exceptions should be catchable for me.

Comment: I Updated the original Question. I totally overlooked the pipe method I call firstly, to notify a GUI. Now I have to find out how to optimize that (if possible without delaying the main functionality such massive as it is now).

Comment: There are two things to note. 1) Microsoft to prevent a Blue Screen made c# bullet proof by making it MANAGED" and put a default exception handler before MAIN is called.  When you get an exception if there is no handle the code moves up the execution stack until the first handle is found and reports the exception. 2) A using Statement does not always report exceptions, it masks the exceptions.  I usually add my own try/catch instead of using. There was no exception handler in REST/WFC code so the exception was reported was misleading.

Comment: The problem here is the line "client.Connect(5000);", because I testet it without the GUI (other end of that pipe) and it shouldn't be neccessary to start the GUI. So that there's a delay of 5 seconds on each thread (at least each task) that affects the main functionality.